# Magento 2 - Pass/Inject data into DataProvider

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, data-provider

I've created a DataProvider to feed data to an ui_component product listing which is displayed in a modal overlay. The modal should display products from a specific subcategory (each subcategory has a Select Products button).

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Ui\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;

/**
 * Class DataProvider
 */
class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $loadedData;

    /**
     * DataProvider constructor.
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);

        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'sku'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'attribute_set_id'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'type_id'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'price'
        );

        $this->collection->joinField(
            'qty',
            'cataloginventory_stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left'
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array|DataObject[]
     */
    public function getData(): array
    {
        $this->loadedData = $this->getCollection()->getItems();

        foreach ($this->getCollection()->getItems() as $item) {
            $this->loadedData['items'][] =  $item->toArray();
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

```
<!-- my/module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml -->

<dataSource name="product_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
    <settings>
        <filterUrlParams>
            <param name="cache_key">*</param>
        </filterUrlParams>
        <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
    </settings>
    <aclResource>Magento_Catalog::products</aclResource>
    <dataProvider class="My\Module\Ui\Product\DataProvider" name="product_listing_data_source">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
            <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>
```

When the **Select Products** button is clicked an AJAX call is made. This will eventually call the data provider and return the product list. At the moment I'm getting all the products in the site. What I need is a list of products filtered by the subcategory_id (corresponding to each **Select Products** button).

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: subcategoriesList, as: 'subcategory'}">
    <div class="subcategory-header clearfix">
        <h1 data-bind="text: subcategory.name"></h1>
        <button data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $parent.openModal($parent, data, event) }" class="secondary action right">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Select Products'"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <!-- .... -->
</div>
```

So in order to achieve my goal I need to pass the subcategory_id to the DataProvider and use it to filter the collection. Is there a way / what would be the best way to pass/inject the subcategory_id into the DataProvider?

I've turned the Internet and M2 docs upside-down and couldn't find a way.

Comment: Is the collection you are using filterable by category_id?

Comment: yes. what do you mean by filtrable?

Comment: If it can be filtered by category_id

Comment: If you have a ui_component for each category and the collection is filterable by category_id just addAttributeToFilter('category_id', take category_id from the request) in the constructor of the data provider. The method I suggest adding is on the collection.